# WPF frame content not updating when source Uri is changed through binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, visual-studio-2013

I've been working on this issue for a few days and can't seem to find anything that will work for my application.

My issue is that I am trying to use a User Control containing buttons to bind to commands which change the source Uri of a frame (both displaying in the same window). When I click a button it is changing the Uri within the ViewModel but the frame does not change the page to reflect this. I believe that it is either not picking up the change due to the way it is binding or there is something blocking it from changing the page which is displaying in the frame.

I am using the MVVM pattern which has been great until I reached the point that I had to start dealing with navigation. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Navigation User Control View Buttons:**

```
<Button Name="BtnMainDash" Content="Main Dashboard" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" Command="{Binding MainDashboard}"/>
<Button Name="BtnAccount" Content="Account" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" Command="{Binding EditAccount}"/>
<Button Name="BtnProjects" Content="Projects" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" Command="{Binding ProjectScreen}"/>
```

**Main Window Frame:**

```
<Frame x:Name="FmePages" Margin="200,30,-0.4,0.4"
               Source="{Binding Path=CurrentPage, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"
               NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
```

**Button ICommands (All the same except that each calls a difference Uri changing command):**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using ScrumManagementApplication.Pages.MainWindow.ViewModel;

namespace ScrumManagementApplication.Pages.MainWindow.Commands
{
    class LoadEditAccount : ICommand
    {
        private readonly NavigationViewModel _navigationViewModel;

        public LoadEditAccount(NavigationViewModel navigationViewModel)
        {
            _navigationViewModel = navigationViewModel;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _navigationViewModel.CommandsEnabled;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _navigationViewModel.LoadEditAccount();
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Input;
using ScrumManagementApplication.Pages.MainWindow.Commands;
using ScrumManagementApplication.SessionData;
using MessageBox = System.Windows.MessageBox;

namespace ScrumManagementApplication.Pages.MainWindow.ViewModel
{
    public class NavigationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
    {
        public bool CommandsEnabled = false;

        public NavigationViewModel()
        {
            MainDashboard = new LoadMainDashboard(this);
            EditAccount = new LoadEditAccount(this);
            ProjectScreen = new LoadProjectScreen(this);
            LogOut = new LoadLogOut(this);

            CommandsEnabled = true;

            LoadEditAccount();
        }

        #region ICommands

        public ICommand MainDashboard { get; private set; }
        public void LoadMainDashboard()
        {
            _currentPage = null;
            _currentPage = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pages/MainWindow/View/MainDashboardView.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);
        }

        public ICommand EditAccount { get; private set; }
        public void LoadEditAccount()
        {
            _currentPage = null;
            _currentPage = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pages/EditUserDetailsPage/View/EditUserDetailsView.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);
        }

        public ICommand ProjectScreen { get; private set; }
        public void LoadProjectScreen()
        {
            _currentPage = null;
            _currentPage = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pages/ProjCreationPage/View/ProjectCreationPage.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);
        }

        public ICommand LogOut { get; private set; }
        public void LoadLogOut()
        {
            var dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to log out?", "Log Out", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);

            if (dialogResult == (MessageBoxResult) DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                App.Current.Shutdown();
            }
        }

        #endregion // ICommands

        #region MainFrame

        private Uri _currentPage;
        public Uri CurrentPage
        {
            get { return _currentPage; }
            set
            {
                _currentPage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPage");
            }
        }

        #endregion // MainFrame

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        #endregion // INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

        protected void OnPropertyChanging(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangingEventHandler handler = PropertyChanging;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any & all help appreciated, even if it doesn't fully solve my issue anything that helps me get closer to a solution is good!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You've got to raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the binding system to update the target property. You are just changing the backing field. Use the property setter that you wrote that automatically raises the `PropertyChanged` event instead.

Comment: @mikez Hi Mike, thanks for your help. I think I might have been staring at my screen for too long as I'm not 100% what you mean, can you elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: Take `LoadEditAccount`, you are changing `_currentPage` without raising a property change event for `CurrentPage`. You need to call `OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPage")` at some point after that. You could just write it as `CurrentPage = new Uri(...);`, which will call your setter and raise the event.

Comment: @mikez I've tried both of those methods but it's still not changing the page in the frame, I added in MessageBoxes to make sure that the Uri was being updated correctly and there's no issue there. For whatever reason the frame just doesn't seem to want to change from it's initial source

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this

`_currentPage = //some value;`

do this:

`CurrentPage = //some value`

The event will be raised when you change the property and not the backing field.

**EDIT**

One more suggestion is to create a single command class since all your commands are setting a string value to a property. You can get the button name using the `CommandParameter`. Based on that set the `Uri`.

Comment: Hi Piyush, thanks for your help. I've tried this an it doesn't seem to work, I don't think that I could be carrying out your instructions wrong as they're fairly simple though just to double check, what should I do with the get; set; for CurrentPage? Thanks again!

Comment: The `get` and `set` will remain same for `CurrentPage`. But you should set the value to property (`CurrentPage`) instead of backing field (`_currentPage`) in methods like `LoadProjectScreen` or `LoadEditAccount`.

Comment: That isn't working either, for some reason it doesn't seem to update the source except for when the command to set it is run inside the initialisation method NavigationViewModel(), once it's set in that it doesn't change again. I can't think of any reason for it as I'm using the same commands inside and outside that method.

Answer (score 0):

Got a similar Problem, had a mainwindow with a frame in it and when I, for example, opened an openfiledialog and closed it, this frame (some others too) did not update even if I called `PropertyChanged()` and the bound Property had the right value. The only solution for me was to remove the binding and handle the Content with NavigationService instead. If you need this Property you bound to for some other approaches you could do something like:

```
    private Page _dataExplorerContent;
    public Page DataExplorerContent
    {
        get { return _dataExplorerContent; }
        set
        {
            if(value != null)
            {
                contentFrame.Navigate(value)
                SetField(ref _dataExplorerContent, value);
            }
        }
    }
```